# What is the Big-O for SQL select?

Tags: sql, mysql, big-o

What is the Big-O for SQL select, for a table with `n` rows and for which I want to return `m` result?

And What is the Big-O for an `Update`, or `delete`, or `Create` operation?

I am talking about mysql and sqlite in general.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727719/database-query-time-complexity

Answer (score 56, accepted):

As you don't control the algorithm selected, there is no way to know directly. However, without indexes a SELECT should be O(n) (a table scan has to inspect every record which means it will scale with the size of the table).

With an index a SELECT is probably O(log(n)) (although it would depend on the algorithm used for indexing and the properties of the data itself if that holds true for any real table). To determine your results for any table or query you have to resort to profiling real world data to be sure.

INSERT without indexes should be very quick (close to O(1)) while UPDATE needs to find the records first and so will be slower (slightly) than the SELECT that gets you there.

INSERT with indexes will probably again be in the ballpark of O(log(n)^2) when the index tree needs to be rebalanced, closer to O(log(n)) otherwise. The same slowdown will occur with an UPDATE if it affects indexed rows, on top of the SELECT costs.

Edit: O(log(n^2)) = O(2log(n)) = O(log(n)) did you mean O(log(n)^2)?

All bets are off once you are talking about JOIN in the mix: you will have to profile and use your databases query estimation tools to get a read on it. Also note that if this query is performance critical you should *re*profile from time to time as the algorithms used by your query optimizer will change as the data load changes.

Another thing to keep in mind... big-O doesn't tell you about fixed costs for each transaction. For smaller tables these are probably higher than the actual work costs. As an example: the setup, tear down and communication costs of a cross network query for a single row will surely be more than the lookup of an indexed record in a small table.

Because of this I found that being able to bundle a group of related queries in one batch can have vastly more impact on performance than any optimization I did to the database proper.

Comment: In line with the comment of the order of a select with a join, bear in mind that a select with a double join to a table can be n^2. For instance; select * from table where id > (select avg(id) from table) probably grows square per record, without using indexes.

Comment: Without reasoning and explanation, this answer appears to be just randomly stating answers to what should be a mathematical and computational process. For example, accessing an entry via primary key could be at a hashtable and constant rate. And why shouldn't it be if it is indexed?

Comment: @T.Woody The point I was trying to make was that without access to the optimizer's output, the performance is database, database version and even data dependant (especially in systems with statistics monitoring that attempt to make good choices). The values I threw around were from memory results that I have seen, but they were illustrative only and yes, pretty arbitrary. Getting your profiler out and use the explain features of your database is the only way to actually know (and that could change as data is loaded).

Answer (score 1):

I think the real answer can only be determined on a case by case basis (database engine, table design, indices, etc.).

However, if you are a MS SQL Server user, you can familiarize yourself with the Estimated Execution Plan in Query Analyzer (2000) or Management Studio (2005+).  That gives you a lot of information you can use for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

All depends on how (well) you write your SQL and how well your database is designed for the operation you are performing.  Try to use the explain plan function to see how things will be executed by the db. The. You can calculate the big-O